# How to run python program files in dragon programming language

Tags: programming-languages

How can I run python program files in dragon programming language??
I have tried all possible means but to no avail..please help
Your answers will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python module
and pyexecFile method

```
select "python"
pyexecFile("filename.py")
```